# How to pass params using fetch API in vuejs vuex store action

Tags: django, vue.js, url, vuex, fetch-api

I am trying to pass a dict using fetch API to django views but unable to get it in request dict of views.
I have tried below steps:

```js
fetch(`/api/getnames`, [{'a': name, 'b': name}])
  .then()
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
  })
```

```py
def getnames(request):
    print(request.__dict__)
```

I am trying to get the dict passed in params while calling the url but dict is not present.
Kindly suggest a solution to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For send parameter(s) you need to use parameter passing by GET or POST method or use a more convenient library like Axios

```
let data = [ {'a': name, 'b': name}];

fetch(`/api/getnames?dict=`+JSON.stringify(data) ) ...
request.GET['dict']

or

fetch('/api/getnames', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({dict: data})
        } ) ...

or

axios.post('/api/getnames', { dict: [ {'a': name, 'b': name}] } );

request.POST['dict']
```